# Does anyone know how to setup WireMock.Net to have cached response?

Tags: mocking

In WireMock.Net, how can we get response cached after first time we're retrieving API? Does anyone know any specific configuration or how to set it up. Thank you in advance.

I tried with different configs as mentioned in WireMock.Net page, but none of them work as expected so far.